# Running ILNumerics application under Mono and SuSE Linux 12.3

Tags: mono, ilnumerics

I'm new to mono and ILNumerics. After downloading the community edition, I wanted to run the 
"Hello ILNumerics! - Core Functionality" application from the ILNumerics Quickstart page.
Compiling (with monodevelop 3.0.6) worked, but when I start the program in x86 debug mode, I
get error messages like:

```
    Unhandled Exception:
    System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer    
    for ILNumerics.ILMath ---> ILNumerics.Exceptions.ILArgumentException: conversion from
    Single to fcomplex is currently not supported.
    at ILNumerics.ILMath.convert[Single,fcomplex] (ILNumerics.ILInArray`1 X) [0x00027] in
    /home/dom/ILNumerics/Functions/builtin/convert.cs:910 
    at ILNumerics.ILMath.tofcomplex (ILNumerics.ILInArray`1 X) [0x00001] in /home/do
    /ILNumerics/Functions/builtin/convert.cs:1633 
    at ILNumerics.Native.ILMKLFFT.FFTForward1D (ILNumerics.ILInArray`1 A, Int32 dim) 
    [0x00072] in /home/dom/ILNumerics/Native/FFT/ILMKLFFT.cs:657 
    at ILNumerics.ILMath.fft (ILNumerics.ILInArray`1 A) [0x0005d] in /home/dom/ILNumeric
    /Functions/builtin/fft.cs:958 
    at ILNumerics.ILMath..cctor () [0x00199] in /home/dom/ILNumerics/Functions   
    /ILMath_General.cs:138 
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /home/do
    /iltesrt/iltesrt/Main.cs:14 
    [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception
    was thrown by the type initializer for ILNumerics.ILMath --->
    ILNumerics.Exceptions.ILArgumentException: conversion from Single to fcomplex is
    currently not supported.
    at ILNumerics.ILMath.convert[Single,fcomplex] (ILNumerics.ILInArray`1 X) [0x00027] in
    /home/dom/ILNumerics/Functions/builtin/convert.cs:910 
    at ILNumerics.ILMath.tofcomplex (ILNumerics.ILInArray`1 X) [0x00001] in /home/do
    /ILNumerics/Functions/builtin/convert.cs:1633 
    at ILNumerics.Native.ILMKLFFT.FFTForward1D (ILNumerics.ILInArray`1 A, Int32 dim)
    [0x00072] in /home/dom/ILNumerics/Native/FFT/ILMKLFFT.cs:657 
    at ILNumerics.ILMath.fft (ILNumerics.ILInArray`1 A) [0x0005d] in /home/dom/ILNumeric
   /Functions/builtin/fft.cs:958 
   at ILNumerics.ILMath..cctor () [0x00199] in /home/dom/ILNumerics/Function
    /ILMath_General.cs:138  
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /home/dom/iltesrt/iltesrt/Main.cs:14
```

I'm doing this on a SuSE 12.3. 32 bit system (but same error on a 64 bit machine), and 
mono version

```
   dom@linux-b0sl:~/ILNumerics> mono --version
    Mono JIT compiler version 3.0.4 (tarball Thu Mar  7 10:35:21 UTC 2013)
    Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue with monodevelop 3.0.3 on ubuntu. Did you try to use the mono version which comes with monodevelop? Or did you try to compile and install mono from an other distro? Might be, there are several runtimes mixed up on your machine?